# Missing ] after element list error in JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script

When I try to save my changes from the `Google Apps Script` file I get the following error:

> Missing ] after element list.

This is my code:

```
  var request = {
    "name": "Name",
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": "Nested",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "variables":[
              [
                "variable": "Var1"
              ]
            ],
            "condition": false,
          },
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
```

The error indicates that the problem is on the line that contains `"variable": allScopes[i].variable`, but I can't find where the problem is...

This is an example with the JSON object that I need to build:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are trying to use the array literal to construct an object:

```
"variables":[
  [
    "variable": "Var1"
  ]
],
```

As it looks like you need an object, not an array here, replace the inner `[]` with `{}`:

```
"variables":[
  {
    "id": null,
    ...,
    "value": ".*"
  }
],
```

Comment: That's true. In this case I need to replace the both `[ ]` and now I'm getting another type of error: `Invalid property ID.`

Comment: Please check my updated question. I have added an example with the JSON object that I need to build.

Comment: So just make each item here the object you need. Add the `id` and `value` and others. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you please explain me why you use `[]` instead of `{}` for `variables` object?

Comment: I receive that error for the following syntax: "variables":{
  {
    "variable": "Var1"
  }
},

Comment: `variables` should be an *array* of *objects*. Please look at my example more carefully and maybe research a bit more about JS literals. It should be  `[ { "variable": "var1" }, { "variable": "var2" }, ... ]` — you get the idea.